# c# error validating email

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I have a register windows form which should insert data for a new account in the database if there is no else account with the email inserted.The problem is that every time it creates the account even if the email is already in the database.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Andrew\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\j2016\j2016\GOOD_FOOD.mdf;Integrated Security=True"))
{
    conn.Open();
    if(parolaLbl.Text == parolaReLbl.Text)
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT email FROM Clienti WHERE email = @email", conn);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", emailLbl.Text);
        var result = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        if(result != emailLbl.Text)
        {
            command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Clienti(parola, nume, prenume, adresa, email) VALUES (@parola, @nume, @prenume, @adresa, @email)";
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parola", parolaLbl.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nume", numeLbl.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prenume", prenumeLbl.Text);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@adresa", adresaLbl.Text);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            eroareLbl.Text = "Cont creat!";
        }
        else
        {
            eroareLbl.Text = "Email deja existent!";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        eroareLbl.Text = "Parolele nu coincid";
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you debug to see what value you have in `result`??

Comment: When you debug, what is the value of `result`?  What is the value of `emailLbl.Text`?

Comment: Have you checked your comparison? String comparisons can be tricky based on setup. You are using `emailLbl.Text` directly. Something as simple as a blank space at the end could break it.

Comment: shouldnt you use `emailTxt.Text` instead of `emailLbl.Text`? Just set a break point and inspect what values have each variable.

Comment: Instead of selecting the email, why not select the `COUNT` and if it is greater than 0, the account exists?

Comment: and if you expect concurrent users to register, you need an atomic statement like `insert ... into ... where not exists()` or wrap both queries in an `SqlTransaction`. you may as well add a unique constraint to the email column and catch the exception.